# Prime Factorization Giving Repeats in JS

Tags: javascript

```
var userNumber = parseInt(prompt("What number would you like to have factored?"));

var factoring = function(n) {
  var m = n;
  var o = n;
  for(i = 2; i < n/2; i++) {
    if (m % i === 0 && o % i === 0) {
      var p = 0;
      while (n % i === 0) {
        n = n / i;
        p++;
      }
      n = m;
      o = o / i;
      if (p > 1) {
        console.log(i + "^" + p);    
      }
      else {
        console.log(i);
      }
    }
    else {}
  }
};

factoring(userNumber);
```

When I feed the above code an input that's large and relatively very composite, it gives wrong answers. 900, for example gives:

```
2^2
3^2
5^2
6^2
```

The first three rows are accurate, but the 6^2 is just a repeat of the 2 and the 3. How do I make the 6^2 not show, as well as solving other similar problems like the extra 25 given when you input 1000?

P.S. I am aware that this code takes more work than is necessary, but I would still rather make it work more or less as is than replace it with some other method entirely.

Comment: Your code has other bugs, besides that repetition. Try getting 10 factored. It gives 2, instead of 2 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting n to its original value by doing `n=m;`. This is the reason, why you get non-prime factors. Also, you don't need `o`. Also, you need to run your outer loop till m/2 + 1, not just till m/2. See the corrected version below.

```js
var userNumber = parseInt(prompt("What number would you like to have factored?"));

var factoring = function(n) {
  var m = n;
  var o = n;
  for(i = 2; i < m/2 + 1; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      var p = 0;
      while (n % i === 0) {
        n = n / i;
        p++;
      }

      if (p > 1) {
        console.log(i + "^" + p);    
      }
      else {
        console.log(i);
      }
    }
    else {}
  }
};

factoring(userNumber);
```

Comment: Try get the factors of 10. It gives only 2. It is still wrong

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares, good catch. See the corrected version.

Comment: For the OP, I recommend you to debug your code more carefully next time, before posting a question here on SO.

Comment: I'm very new to coding. That was the result of half an hour of staring at the code not knowing how to fix it. I wouldn't have posted if I hadn't tried to fix it. Thanks for helping.